# hbase table design for bank transaction data

Tags: hbase

I want to store bank transaction details in Hbase. I am going to design a rule engine using drools and want to load the transaction data from the incoming kafka and lookup against the hbase table. What should be the rowid. below is the sample data columns. A person can have multiple transactions. some of the rules is like if more then 5 transactions in 15 mins.

```
Account_Number, Transaction _Amount, Reciever_Account_Bank_Type,    Transaction_Date,   Transaction_Time, Account_Reg_Date
```